# Tutorials/WritingServiceClient(python) - beginner_tutorials.srv

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient(python)

I am missing a step where beginner_tutorials.srv is created.

Somewhat expected, when running add_two_ints_server.py I get the error

> ImportError: No module named
> beginner_tutorials.srv

Trying to use AddTwoInts.srv instead did not get me anywhere ..

Here is CmakeList.txt

```
project(beginner_tutorials)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)
 add_message_files(
   FILES
   Num.msg
 )
add_service_files(
  FILES
  AddTwoInts.srv
)
 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
 )
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES beginner_tutorials
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_runtime
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

Here is package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>beginner_tutorials</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The beginner_tutorials package</description>

  <maintainer email="z@todo.todo">z</maintainer>

  <license>TODO</license>

<build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
<run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>

  <export>
  </export>
</package>
```

Here is the content of srv directory

```
z@z-P5Q-EM:~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/srv$ ls
AddTwoInts.srv  beginner_tutorials.srv
z@z-P5Q-EM:~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/srv$ cat AddTwoInts.srv 
int64 a
int64 b
---
int64 sum
z@z-P5Q-EM:~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/srv$ cat beginner_tutorials.srv 
int64 a
int64 b
---
int64 sum
```

rossrv output

```
z@z-P5Q-EM:~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/srv$ rossrv show beginner_tutorials.srv
[beginner_tutorials/beginner_tutorials]:
int64 a
int64 b
---
int64 sum

z@z-P5Q-EM:~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/srv$ rossrv show AddTwoInts
[beginner_tutorials/AddTwoInts]:
int64 a
int64 b
---
int64 sum

[rospy_tutorials/AddTwoInts]:
int64 a
int64 b
---
int64 sum
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203524/tutorials/writingserviceclient(python)---beginner_tutorials.srv/) by [CroWizCom](https://answers.ros.org/users/20286/crowizcom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-02-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-02-21**:
Have you successfully run `catkin_make`? That is what should actually convert the service definition into Python and C++ code that can be used in a node. Also, make sure that you have sourced your `setup.bash` in the terminal you are running the server in.

**Comment by [CroWizCom](https://answers.ros.org/users/20286/crowizcom/) on 2015-02-21**:
catkin_make runs fine, just like tutorials up to that point.
in .bashrc I have

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

**Comment by [CroWizCom](https://answers.ros.org/users/20286/crowizcom/) on 2015-02-21**:
catkin_make output

```
-- beginner_tutorials: 1 messages, 1 services
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was in `.bashrc`.
I entered `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` there, but `export PYTHONPATH ...`, that somehow got populated few lines down, overrided the proper setting.
So I moved  `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` to the end of the `.bashrc` and everything is swell now.

---

Originally posted by [CroWizCom](https://answers.ros.org/users/20286/crowizcom/) with karma: 16 on 2015-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0